# Replaced ThinkPad T510 battery, DVD drive randomly opens

Tags: windows-10, battery, dvd, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

I recently replaced the battery in my ThinkPad T510 (running Windows 10) with a new OEM battery and throughout the day the CD/DVD drive randomly opens.  It is the weirdest thing as I will be typing in a meeting, doing work, or the laptop is just sitting open and the drive does a "click" and simply ejects itself.  Sometimes 5 times in less than 10 minutes and other times nothing for over an hour.  It can be plugged in, docked, running on battery, freshly rebooted, coming back from a sleep, or sitting open for hours.  It is completely random.

This didn't happen before I put the new battery in so after a few weeks I switched back to the old battery to see if the same behavior occurred.  Nope, nothing happened.  The drive never opened with the old battery and the laptop worked as expected.  After a couple days, I switched the battery back to the new one and the drive went back to randomly opening.  I've run diagnostics (both Lenovo and Windows) and nothing is found.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?  It doesn't appear to hurt anything other than my ego and I can only assume the people I'm meeting with are wondering why I keep pressing eject on my DVD drive (when I'm not doing anything).

**EDIT:**  I followed John's suggestion and updated all drivers and software that I could find from Lenovo and still no change in behavior.  (Windows 10 was up to date already.)  I will run another test with the original battery but the new battery is still opening the drive randomly.

**SECOND EDIT:**  I've tested now with 3 different Linux distros as a LiveCD and also installing Linux Mint.  The same issue occurs with the new battery versus old battery.  Seeing as this is an older laptop, I'm just going to chalk it up to the battery being haunted and deal with it until I can afford a new one.

Comment: Make sure the battery is a Lenovo Battery and then update the Power Driver for the laptop

Comment: The battery is definitely a Lenovo battery (bought directly from Lenovo) but I will try updating the power driver and see if that helps.

Comment: You might also run System Update (Control Panel) to update all drivers that need updating.

Comment: @John - updated everything I could find and no change.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Just run the laptop with new battery & any Live Linux distro like Ubuntu or Mint thru USB and keep it plugged in overnight. See if next day the tray has ejected or not. In Device Manager if DVD-ROM or something similar is seen as a device then see if uninstall along with remove driver software helps. Upon next boot it should pick the default Windows driver. Not too sure if this would matter but in case there's any recent BIOS update for your laptop, try updating to a newer version. Is there any option to calibrate Battery in BIOS? If not let it fully discharge to 5% and then charge to 100%.

Comment: Good suggestion!  Thanks, @patkim.  I will give that a try next.

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting behavior for sure. Have you checked to make sure the button on the cd/dvd drive is not sticking? If not I would definitely contact Lenovo directly about this issue.

Comment: Double checked the button on the side of the drive and it doesn't appear to be stuck.  It works as expected when pushing the button and doesn't seem to be loose either.  Thank you for the suggestion.